# How to parse String output of a tensorflow model

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Created a model using the code here : https://gist.github.com/gaganmalhotra/1424bd3d0617e784976b29d5846b16b1

To get the predictions of the probabilites in java it can be done using below code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = SavedModelBundle.load("/Users/gagandeep.malhotra/Documents/SampleTF_projects/tf_iris_model/1510707746/", "serve").session();

    Tensor x =
        Tensor.create(
            new long[] {2, 4},
            FloatBuffer.wrap(
                new float[] {
                  6.4f, 3.2f, 4.5f, 1.5f,
                  5.8f, 3.1f, 5.0f, 1.7f
                }));

    final String xName = "Placeholder:0";
    final String scoresName = "dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0";

    List<Tensor<?>> outputs = session.runner()
        .feed(xName, x)
        .fetch(scoresName)
        .run();

    // Outer dimension is batch size; inner dimension is number of classes
    float[][] scores = new float[2][3];

    outputs.get(0).copyTo(scores);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scores));
  }
```

**However if we want to copy over the predicted classes (string type) for the code below:**

```
final String xName = "Placeholder:0";
final String className = "dnn/head/predictions/str_classes:0";

List<Tensor<?>> outputs = session.runner()
    .feed(xName, x)
    .fetch(className)
    .run();

// Outer dimension is batch size; inner dimension is number of classes
String[][] classes = new String[2][1];

outputs.get(0).copyTo(classes);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(classes));
```

I end up with an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot copy Tensor with 2 dimensions into an object with 1
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.throwExceptionIfTypeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:739)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:450)
    at deeplearning.IrisTFLoad.main(IrisTFLoad.java:71)
```

**But the dimension is same as the output tensor: [STRING tensor with shape [2, 1]]**

PS: The signature definition can be found as below -

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['x'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 4)
        name: Placeholder:0
    The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/ExpandDims:0
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/str_classes:0
    outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 3)
        name: dnn/head/logits:0
    outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 3)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
    Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Things tried :

Tensor tensor = (Tensor) outputs.get(0);
   byte[][][] result = tensor.copyTo(new byte[2][1][]);

but errors out as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid DataType(7)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.readNDArray(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:451)
    at deeplearning.IrisTFLoad.main(IrisTFLoad.java:74)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DT_STRING` typed TensorFlow tensors contain [arbitrary byte sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/DataType) as elements, not Java `String`s (sequence of characters).

Thus, what you want is something like this:

```
byte[][][] classes = new byte[2][1][];
outputs.get(0).copyTo(classes);
```

If you'd like to get Java `String` objects, then you'll need to know what encoding your model produces the classes in, and then could do something like (assuming UTF-8 encoding):

```
String[][] classesStrings = new String[2][1];
for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < classes[i].length; ++j) {
    classesString[i][j] = new String(classes[i][j], UTF_8);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.
You might also find the [unittest](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/TensorTest.java#L393) instructive.